# Can you get image file name from assetURL in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, alassetslibrary

I'm saving images to photolibrary using ALAssetsLibrary and printing out the url of the image file.  I noticed that photos are saved to the ios device with IMG_####.jpg format where #### is some number.  I would like to get the filename of the image that I just saved. Anyway to get this IMG_####.jpg file name from the url?

```
assetLib.writeImage(toSavedPhotosAlbum: imageToSave.cgImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: imageToSave.imageOrientation.rawValue)!, completionBlock: {(url,error) -> Void in
            print("image url: \(url)")
```

output

```
image url: Optional(assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=56963951-1CE3-4A1A-B693-804899C79BA5&ext=JPG)
```

In the comments of this link there is someone doing exactly what I want however I'm not too familiar with objective C and not using imagePickerController.  If someone could explain to me how to do this in Swift without imagePickerController that would be awesome.

http://ootips.org/yonat/how-to-set-the-image-name-when-saving-to-the-camera-roll/

Comment: "the filename of the image" What filename are you even talking about? An image is not a file — it's an image. And you know how to get to this image; it is stored as data, in a file at this asset URL that you yourself have given. So what's the problem, exactly? Further information (i.e. the `IMG_####.jpg`) would not even be useful, since you can't use it to access the image.

Comment: When I connect my iphone to my PC I see the images in a folder called DCIM with IMG_####.jpg format.  I want to get the image file name when I save the image to photo library.

Comment: But why? You haven't explained that. Distinguish two uses of the word "I" here. The "I" who connects the phone to the computer is a human being. But the "I" who represents the program never sees that name and cannot use it for anything, so what's the reason why the program wants to know it?

Comment: You are assuming that the program is doing everything.  The program is simply recording data with each image so that I can process the images later.  How am I suppose to know this image with the 2 trees goes with data recording #432 if I don't know the name of the image in the file?

Comment: By keeping track of its Asset URL and any other necessary information. Or store everything elsewhere, such as the Temporary folder.

Comment: Those 2 suggestions don't seem like they would work for my case and if my data gets deleted from Temporary folder it would be disasterious.

Comment: "don't seem like they would work for my case" They are not really suggestions, since you have not even said what "your case" _is_. I have asked you several times what you are really trying to do and you have not answered me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone else is interested in doing the same thing.  Credits to the link I posted in question I just translated it to Swift.

```
    let assetLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
    //Save image get access to the url in completion handler    
    assetLib.writeImage(toSavedPhotosAlbum: imageToSave.cgImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: imageToSave.imageOrientation.rawValue)!, completionBlock: {(url,error) -> Void in
                        let phAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url!], options: nil)
                        let lastPhAsset = phAsset.lastObject
                        let asset = assetLib.asset(for: url, resultBlock: {(asset) -> Void in
                            //print("Asset Success!")
                            let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
                            imageRequestOptions.isSynchronous = true
                            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: lastPhAsset!, options: imageRequestOptions, resultHandler: {
                                (data,string,orientation,diction) -> Void in


                                let filename = diction![AnyHashable("PHImageFileURLKey")]!
                                // You should have the correct filename here.
                                //print("Filename = \(filename)")
                            })

                        }, failureBlock: {(error) -> Void in
                            print("Failed to retrieve a asset from url.")
                            return
                        })


  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The important point is, you cannot do anything using the image names that presented in the asset url.

You have to store the `asset-url` instead to retrieve the image back from the photo-library.